# Difference between doLast and leftShift on Gradle task?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am aware of the difference between passing in a configuration closure and defining an action for a task. I believe you can't use `<<` in a configuration closure because it seems like a syntax error:

```
task wrong {
  << { println "From doLast" }
}
```

But. Why can't I use `leftShift` as an equivalent of `<<` in the above configuration closure? In an even more clear test case, why doesn't the following buildfile output the line `From leftShift - inside`?

```
defaultTasks 'tryout'

task tryout {
  doLast { println "From doLast" }
  leftShift { println "From leftShift - inside" }
}

tryout.leftShift { println "From leftShift - outside" }
```

Of course, this is not a real problem, as I can simply use doLast. I'm just trying to broaden my understanding of Gradle. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

`<<` when used with a task definition, is **not** really a leftshift in the bitwise sense. It is shorthand for `doLast`. In gradle DSL:

```
task hello << {
    println 'Hello world!'
}
```

is exactly the same as:

```
task hello {
    doLast{
        println 'Hello world!'
    }
}
```

Comment: So how does it work? Hoe does Groovy know `<<` is shorthand for `doLast`?

Comment: Because you can overload operators in groovy

Comment: totally have situations where they are not the same.