# Gradle: Differences when define task with and without << operator

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-task

I'm using Gradle and I try to configure for my Android project. I read document and I see that there are two ways of defining a task.

**Without << Operator**

```
task SampleTask {
    methodA param1 param2
}
```

**With << Operator:**

```
Task SampleTask <<{
   methodA param1 param2
}
```

My question is: what is real differences between above 2 ways?

Thanks :)

Comment: it's a shortand for defining your task 
read here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html

Comment: See here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/35386910/745574

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define tasks like this :

```
task hello {
    doLast {
        println 'Hello world!'
    }
}
```

here, the last thing that `hello` task does, is to print 'Hello World!' 
I can use another syntax for defining my task like this :

```
task hello << {
    println 'Hello world!'
}
```

these two tasks are same.
another example is :

```
task hello << {
    println 'Hello Earth'
}
hello.doFirst {
    println 'Hello Venus'
}
hello.doLast {
    println 'Hello Mars'
}
hello << {
    println 'Hello Jupiter'
}
```

now the output will be :

```
Hello Venus
Hello Earth
Hello Mars
Hello Jupiter
```

read [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html) for more details.